# Where is ERROR_PENDING defined?

Tags: winapi, header

[The MSDN documentation for CommitTransactionAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366004(v=VS.85).aspx) indicates it may produce an `ERROR_PENDING` error code. However, this error code does not seem to be defined in `winerror.h`, nor any other header reachable from `ktmw32.h` or `windows.h` (using the version of the Windows SDK included in Visual Studio 2010). In fact, I cannot find a single file containing the text `ERROR_PENDING` anywhere in the Windows SDK 7.1; manually going through the list of [System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381(v=VS.85).aspx) doesn't reveal it either. Where can I find the definition of this elusive error code?

Experimentation shows `CommitTransactionAsync` to produce `ERROR_SUCCESS` - is this a simple matter of the documentation being wrong?

Comment: Just a guess, but could it be a typo and they really meant ERROR_IO_PENDING ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a doc bug.  @flashk's guess is correct: it can produce `ERROR_IO_PENDING`.  I am submitting a bug to the doc owner today.  Thanks!